# How to replace all list of list items with the index value of that list

Tags: python, list, replace

I am trying to replace items in list of lists by the value of the index of that specific list. I can do it with a for loop, but I was wondering if there is a faster way to do this.

such that the following list

```
example = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]
```

becomes:

```
solution = [[0, 0, 0], [1, 1, 1], [2, 2, 2]]
```

Answer (score 1):

Your way with `for` loop should work, but if you want another way in a short version then you can do it this way with [list comprehension](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/list-comprehension) and [enumerate](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/methods/built-in/enumerate),

```
example = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]
result = [[index] * len(value) for index, value in enumerate(example)]
print(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

List comprehensions are usually faster than loops

Here is a solution with list comprehensions

```py
example = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]
solution = [[x for _ in range(len(example[x]))] for x in range(len(example))]
print(solution)
```

```
Output
[[0, 0, 0], [1, 1, 1], [2, 2, 2]]
```

Comment: Why not use `enumerate()`? And you can use multiplication to produce lists of a certain length.

Answer (score 0):

```py
solution = [[i]*len(x) for i, x in enumerate(example)]
```

Comment: Rather than only post a block of code, please *explain* why this code solves the problem posed. Without an explanation, this is not really an answer. Besides, the code is essentially identical that in the answer by Always Sunny, who updated their answer based on comments *before you posted this one*.

Answer (score -1):

Here is a solution with the `map` function:

```
res = list(map(lambda i : [i] * len(example[i]),
            range(len(example))
        ))
print(res)
```

It's more verbose than the comprehension method, but coming from other languages I prefer it - I find the `map` to be more explicit and easier to follow, as it's built out of the common components of higher-order functions rather than having its own syntax.

Comment: I disagree that this is easier to follow. It's a lot more verbose, for starters.

Comment: But it doesn't require you to know the ins and outs of python for comprehensions. For me, I find that the comprehension model looks nice, but it's harder to disentangle to what exactly is done with each position, while `map` is a concept any programmer in a modern language should grok. Verbosity can mean clarity.

Comment: List comprehensions are [not unique to Python](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_comprehension), though.

Comment: I'm not sure of other languages that use python-esque syntax, but the `map` model exists in every halfway decent language I'm familiar with. I also just find comprehensions get messy as you start to add to them (like, nested comprehensions, if expressions, whatever.) As someone who switches between languages often, I'd rather use the very common and standard language of function calls, rather than try to piece together exactly what will bind to what or execute when for a language-specific construct.

Comment: Yes, verbosity can aid clarity, but only if you actually *use it to add clarity*. Like using separate variables with clear names to break down a complex expression into its  constituent parts.

Comment: You can mess up list comprehension clarity just like you can mess up anything in code. That's not the fault of the syntax, however.

Comment: For starters, rather than use `range(len(example))` and then using the index to get back each value, why not use `enumerate()`? Use it with [`starmap()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.starmap) instead of `map()`, and you can already reduce the amount of code one has to parse here. Each language has _idiomatic code patterns_, I always try to learn those patterns when working in another programming language. List comprehensions are a Python idiomatic pattern.

Comment: Sure, but with the `map` thing, you're only using the most bedrock of concepts - function calls. Anyone coming from Java, Scala, C, whatever, will be immediately familiar with what's happening. To be fair I dislike Python in general, so I'm certainly biased, and given to cynicism regarding its expressions.

Comment: `enumerate` sounds like a good call, though, I'll edit that in (and read about `starmap`).

Comment: That's not very helpful then if you want to provide answers here, where there are a lot of Python experts that do know the language.

Comment: Fundamental disagreement there - critics of a system have valuable input on a system. That's usually part of my approach to anything in CS - "How can we minimize the damage this can do" as opposed to "How can we get the most out of this." This does all come down to a matter of taste, though, and I don't expect either of us to persuade the other.

Comment: I know about the value of criticism, that doesn't mean I have to _agree_.

Comment: I feel like we're both saying we agree to disagree.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/249912/discussion-between-edward-peters-and-martijn-pieters).